# Why doesn't this show the next pdf but the first pdf always?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter. I'm working on a project which has to create PDFs according to the user inputs. In the first input it creates the PDF and previews it. But in next inputs it doesn't show me the new PDF but the old one. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Packages I use to preview and to create the pdf.

```
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
```

Code to create the pdf.

```
final pdf = pw.Document();

  writeOnPdf() {
    String name = controllerName.text;
    String drugs = controllerDrugs.text;
    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Header(level: 0, child: pw.Text("Methsuwa Family Clinics", 
style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 40)) ),
            pw.Header(child: pw.Text('Name :- ' + name, style: 
pw.TextStyle(fontSize:16))),
        pw.Paragraph(text: 'Medications :-'),
        pw.Paragraph(text: drugs)
          ];
        }));
  }
```

This is the function I use to save the pdf.

```
  Future savePdf() async {
    String name = controllerName.text;
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
    File file = File("$documentPath/" + name + ".pdf");
    file.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
}
```

Calling the pdf.

```
     onPressed: () async {

          String name = controllerName.text;

          // Add your onPressed code here!
          writeOnPdf();
          await savePdf();

          Directory documentDirectory =
              await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
          String fullPath = ("$documentPath/" + name + ".pdf"); // name is the file name which user inputs.

          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PdfPreviewScreen(path: fullPath)));
```

This is the PDF showing class.

```
class PdfPreviewScreen extends StatelessWidget{
    final String path;
  
    PdfPreviewScreen({this.path});
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: null,
            tooltip: "Navigation Menu",
          ),
          title: Text("Methsuwa Family Clinics"),
        ),
        body: PDFViewerScaffold(path: path),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please also clarify which pakage you are using to create and view pdf. Also add the code of creating the pdf.

Comment: @DC sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for providing more info but you still forgot to provide how you are taking input for creating pdf.  I think the `writeOnPdf()` is used for that.

Comment: @DC I'm Sorry for not providing necessary details.

Comment: It's good that you found the issue. At first, I thought that you want new data in the same pdf but as a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full working code with new pdf every time:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final nameText = TextEditingController();
  final drugsText = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameText.dispose();
    drugsText.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: nameText,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter Name',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: drugsText,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter Drug',
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  String name = nameText.text;
                  String drugs = drugsText.text;

                  var pdf = pw.Document(); //pdf document
                  
                  // Pdf creation
                  writeOnPdf() {
                    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
                        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
                        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
                        build: (pw.Context context) {
                          return <pw.Widget>[
                            pw.Header(
                                level: 0,
                                child: pw.Text("Methsuwa Family Clinics",
                                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 40))),
                            pw.Header(
                                child: pw.Text('Name :- ' + name,
                                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 16))),
                            pw.Paragraph(text: 'Medications :-'),
                            pw.Paragraph(text: drugs)
                          ];
                        }));
                  }

                  //Saving pdf
                  Future savePdf() async {
                    Directory documentDirectory =
                        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

                    String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
                    File file = File("$documentPath/" + name + ".pdf");
                    file.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
                  }


                  writeOnPdf();
                  await savePdf();

                  Directory documentDirectory =
                      await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
                  String fullPath = ("$documentPath/" + name + ".pdf");

                  //Opening created pdf
                  OpenFile.open(fullPath);
                },
                child: Text('Click To Create PDF'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, Add these in Pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  pdf: ^3.3.0
  open_file: ^3.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final pdf = pw.Document();

  writeOnPdf() {
    String name = controllerName.text;
    String drugs = controllerDrugs.text;
    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Header(level: 0, child: pw.Text("Methsuwa Family Clinics", 
style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 40)) ),
            pw.Header(child: pw.Text('Name :- ' + name, style: 
pw.TextStyle(fontSize:16))),
        pw.Paragraph(text: 'Medications :-'),
        pw.Paragraph(text: drugs)
          ];
        }));
  }
```

Here I'm updating the same variable called pdf again and again when I want to create. Not only that I have created a muli page pdf. So I'm making a new page in every single time I run it. That is the problem with my code.